# How to create MSIX package for Microsoft App Store for an Electron app?

Tags: electron, windows-store, msix, microsoft-store

How can I publish my Electron app to Microsoft Store?

Microsoft Partner Center gives 3 options for creating an app:

1. MSIX or PWA app
2. EXE or MSI app
3. Game

[image: Microsoft Partner Center screenshot]

I assume that MSIX format is preferable. electron-windows-store tool produces AppX packages only and [appears to be dead](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-windows-store/issues/132).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [distribute and update electron desktop app using microsoft store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63056238/distribute-and-update-electron-desktop-app-using-microsoft-store)

Comment: @BogdanMitrache I would prefer a free tool. Advanced Installer Free does not include MSIX packaging, according to https://www.advancedinstaller.com/feats-list.html

Comment: AppX and MSIX are basically the same thing. I believe selecting MSIX should let you upload an AppX as well. To support Windows 10 older than 1709 tools used to create Appx packages. The main difference is the file name extension.